# Does a closed form solution exist for $x$?

Tags: closed-form, radicals

$$ \sqrt{x} + x^2 = \sqrt{2} $$
If so, how would one find it?

Comment: Isn't solving $y+y^4 = \sqrt{2}$, for $y>0$, the same thing?

Comment: The quartic formula would work (using the hint of Integral). However, the quartic formula is awful.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Newton's method doesn't give you a closed form, but an approximation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $u = \sqrt{x}$: $$u + u^4 = \sqrt{2}$$

There is a general formula for the quartic, though it is rather disgusting.

$$u = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(9+\sqrt{3 \left(27+512
   \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}+\frac{4\ 2^{5/6}}{\sqrt[3]{3 \left(9+\sqrt{3
   \left(27+512 \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(9+\sqrt{3 \left(27+512 \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{4\
   2^{5/6}}{\sqrt[3]{3 \left(9+\sqrt{3 \left(27+512
   \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)}}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(9+\sqrt{3 \left(27+512 \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{4\
   2^{5/6}}{\sqrt[3]{3 \left(9+\sqrt{3 \left(27+512 \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)}}}$$

Comment: Why do you give only one solution?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp There are two real solutions to $u + u^4 = \sqrt{2}$. One of those solutions squares to something bigger than $1$, which cannot be a solution to $\sqrt{x} + x^2 = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I see, thanks..

Comment: Can't any of those radicals be unnested to yield something a *bit* nicer?

Comment: That can be simplified by simply naming $v = \left(9+\sqrt{3(27+512\sqrt{2})}\right)^{1/3}$

Comment: The answer is almost there, but it does not answer the question: You should rewrite the quartic in terms of $x$, and also, how the solution was found was not explained.